# how can i make this filter with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

i coding a social media aplication. I have a problem with profile menu in profile page. I want it to be visible menu items depending on certain circumstancesces. I did put menu items in a array like this;

```
$scope.menuitems = [
    {id : "1", name : "Message", show : "other", url : ""},
    {id : "2", name : "Follow", show : "other", url : ""},
    {id : "3", name : "Followers", show : "all", url : ""},
    {id : "4", name : "About", show : "all", url : ""},
    {id : "5", name : "Statistics", show : "all", url : ""},
    {id : "6", name : "Edit", show : "own", url:""}
];
```

İf the visible profile is the user's own profile, i want to print items with 'show' value 'own'. If the visible profile is a another user's profile, i want to print items with 'show' value 'other'. And i want to print items with 'show' value 'all' in every stuation. I did a little research on the internet for this but I guess I have not found the right words. How i make this with ng-repeat on Angularjs?

Comment: you can do only 1 filter at a time

Comment: For example if visible profile is user's own profile, i want to make like this if(item.show != 'other'). But i could not find how to write in ng-repeat @Sajeetharan

Comment: On which $scope variable you keep the visible profile?

Comment: $scope.areyou @TomePejoski

Comment: @EnesGiray and on that object you have the `show` attribute as well right?

Comment: if $scope.areyou is true, i want it to listed items with 'show' value 'other' not. @TomePejoski

Comment: So then I guess `$scope.areyou` should be undefined in order to show *all*, right?

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to showed all items. İf $scope.areyou is false, i want it to listed items with 'show' value 'own' not. @TomePejoski

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134214/discussion-between-tome-pejoski-and-enes-giray).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom filter

```
    $scope.conditionVar = 'own'; //this will change depending on what profile

    angular.module('myFilters', []).
  filter('profilefilter', function() {
    return function(items, condition) {
      var out = [];
      for (var i in items) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item.show === 'all' || item.show === condition) {
            out.push(item);
        }
      }
      return out;
    }
  });
    <li ng-repeat="menuitem in menuitems | profilefilter:conditionVar">{{menuitem}}</li>
```

here is the working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/0o7ewpgd/1/

Comment: I tried but it not worked I tried but it not worked. I didn't get any errors but elements not listed

Comment: I wrote your codes only by changing the variable names

Comment: You need to take the logic implementation of this code peice, also a bit from your end as well as we dont have the code available

Comment: I prepared this example by look your example; https://jsfiddle.net/Enesozgry/bx5dxc6d/3/

Comment: I had misunderstand filter logic. I solved my problem. Thank you :)